# How do I use url_for in wtf before the app has initialized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I was wondering how I could use the `url_for()` function from flask in an wtf form class before the app has initialized.
My form class looks like this:

```
class UserRegisterForm(FlaskForm):
    accept_terms = BooleanField(
        "I have read the <a href=\"{{ url_for('terms_of_service') }}\">terms of service</a><br> and I 
        agree with them.", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Now, you see, I'm trying to use `url_for()` function in the label text. Unfortunately that does not work.
I am not able to use the function outside of the label because the I get an rumtime error, because I'm using the function before the website is getting generated.
Who has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create the url outside of the label:

```
terms_url = url_for('terms_of_service')

accept_terms = BooleanField(f"I have read the {terms_url}...")
```